# Tengo un error al ingresar el mercado pago SDK

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php7, mercadopago

Tengo un error en la pagina al integrar el sdk de mercado pago. Me da el error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "MercadoPago\SDK" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\auncios\index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\auncios\index.php on line 3

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

try {
    if (isset($_GET['collection_id'])) {
        $collectionId = $_GET['collection_id'];

        $payment = MercadoPago\Payment::find_by_id($collectionId);

        if ($payment->status == 'approved') {
            $montoRecibido = $payment->transaction_amount;
            $usuarioId = $_SESSION['usuario_id']; // Reemplaza con la lógica para obtener el ID del usuario

            $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tu_base_de_datos', 'tu_usuario', 'tu_contraseña');
            $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE usuarios SET presupuesto = presupuesto + :monto WHERE id = :usuarioId");
            $stmt->bindParam(':monto', $montoRecibido, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':usuarioId', $usuarioId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();

            // Redirige a una página de confirmación
            header('Location: pago-exitoso.php');
        } else {
            // Redirige a una página de pago fallido
            header('Location: pago-fallido.php');
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Manejo de excepciones
    // Puedes registrar o mostrar un mensaje de error
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: pareciera que no esta instalado el sdk intenta hacer un "composer dump-autoload"

Comment: ¿Tienes instalada la última versión de la librería? Me temo que estás usando código antiguo. Revisa los ejemplos de código en [Github](https://github.com/mercadopago/sdk-php). Por ejemplo, para setear el token se usa: `MercadoPagoConfig::setAccessToken('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');` Y no olvides poner los `use` al principio. Revisa la [guía de migración](https://github.com/mercadopago/sdk-php/blob/master/MIGRATION_GUIDE.md) si estabas usando la versión 2 y has pasado a la versión 3.

Answer (score 0):

Cambió muchísimo la nueva SDK y todavía no hay buena documentación o ejemplos claros para todas las funciones anteriores. Yo, para evitar reprogramar todo, de momento -hasta que tenga tiempo- sigo con la versión anterior.

Podes instarla así:

```
composer require "mercadopago/dx-php:2.6.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

La ultima versión del SDK, trabaja con PHP Versión 8.2., Solucione el problema actualizando la versión de PHP a la Versión 8.2.